# Trouble submitting paper to arXiv - labels except in equations

Tags: equations, labels, arxiv

I submitted my tex file with figures to the Arxiv. References and figures are well referenced, but equations no.

When I compile the tex file in my computer using,

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
equation here
\end{equation}
```

and then reference to it with either `\ref{eq:1}` or `\eqref{eq:1}` it works correctly, but it is not working for arxiv.

I am using `aps` format

Answer (score 3):

The problem arsises with the use of the `clevref` package. Eliminating it solves the problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure you mean the `cleveref` package. Is this really the solution?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine if there is no special character in the label. For instance,

```
    \begin{equation}\label{eqOne}
        equation here
    \end{equation}
```

causes no problem.

Comment: This *should* have no bearing on the problem. The current answer (from the OP) points to an additional package being the cause of the problem.